# Eating non vegetarian food?

Tags: non-vegetarian

According to vedas killing and eating animal meat are forbidden and also a sin to hindus but according to manusmiriti eating non-veg is allowed.So which is true, Manusmiriti or Vedas?  and which should I follow ?

Comment: First of all, eating non veg or not is left to you. It depends on yourself completely. At the same time Manusmiriti even states eating non veg is sin. And both Manusmiriti and Vedas are true in their own way. We cannot judge it.

Comment: One can never obtain meat without causing injury to living beings, he should therefore abstain from meat. Reflecting on how meat is obtained and on how embodied creatures are tied up and killed, he should quit eating any kind of meat. The man who authorizes, the man who butchers, the man who slaughters, the man who buys or sells, the man who cooks, the man who serves, and the man who eats – these are all killers. They is no greater sinner than a man who, outside of offering to gods or ancestors, wants to make his own flesh thrive at the expense of someone else's.
— Manusmriti, 5.48-5.52

Comment: Just ask yourself: 'why do i want to eat meat'. If it is 'for survival' then no scripture would condone it. If it is for 'tastes better', then by abstaining from meat, you're doing one step in your sadhana to control your senses! There is of course karma in everything. That includes killing insects, killing plants, etc. If your goal is to reduce karma, then it may or may not be successful. If your goal is to realize the Self, Overcome the sway of your senses, then definitely controlling meat is a helpful tool, although not a must (just like anything else). Good luck

Comment: where in the vedas does it forbid eating of meat? Can you give a specific reference?

Answer (score 7):

What Bhagavat Gita says is,

> 1. Sattva (the quality of goodness): Sattva is Calm, Saintly. Its
>    brings up quality that allows spiritual holiness, forgiveness and
>    submission to God. Foods dear to those in the mode of goodness
>    increase the duration of life, purify one’s existence and give
>    strength, health, happiness and satisfaction. Such foods are juicy,
>    fatty, wholesome, and pleasing to the heart. [(BG 17.8)](https://www.vedabase.com/en/bg/17/8)
> 2. Raja (the quality of passion): Foods that are too bitter, too sour,
>    salty, hot, pungent, dry and burning are dear to those in the mode
>    of passion. Such foods cause distress, misery and disease. Onions
>    and garlic fall into this category. [(BG 17.9)](https://www.vedabase.com/en/bg/17/9)
> 3. Tamas (the quality of ignorance): Food prepared more than three
>    hours before being eaten, food that is tasteless, decomposed and
>    putrid, and food consisting of remnants and untouchable things is
>    dear to those in the mode of darkness. [(BG 17.10)](https://www.vedabase.com/en/bg/17/10)

As per Manusmiriti,

> One can eat meat when his life is in danger i.e. if the condition is
> such that if you don't eat meat you will die. [Manusmiriti - 5.27]

---

Both of these books did not ban non vegetarian food completely. They highly encourage vegetarian food and treat it as the quality of god. They allow non vegetarian food but discourage it heavily.

As far as I see both of the books tell us the same thing.